# How to implement static web server with node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I want to use node.js & express as a static server. I want it to serve all views without having to explicitly define routes. How do I do this?

Comment: Sounds like you would be better of with something like nginx, but just add the standard express static route and use files for everything, and it's all static ?

Comment: Its not all static, but I do not want to hardcode all my static routes.

Comment: Why on earth would you have to hardcode anything? Just add `app.use(express.static(__dirname));` and the middleware takes care of all URL's that match a static resource.

Comment: Cool. I am a noob and didn't know that's how that worked. I'll just place the static html files into the public folder. If you write this as an answer I will vote on it.

Answer (score 1):

To serve static files you can use the middleware provided by Express, just add

```
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname));
```

after your dynamic routes.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use node.js as a static file server, use nginx instead. But if you have to or you are just playing with node, you can use this (coffeescript):

Handle static files:

```
app.use '/public/', express.static(__dirname + '/public')
```

Example:

```
<img src="/public/logo.jpg" alt="" />
```

Handle single app page:

```
app.get '/', (req, res)->
   res.sendfile './public/index.html'
```